# Apache 2.4 basic auth don't work

Tags: apache-httpd, authentication

I have a problem with basic auth in apache 2.4. I have these lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@email.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/foo
    ServerName my.domain.com

<Directory /var/www/html/foo/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Authentication Required"
        AuthUserFile "/etc/httpd/.htpasswd"
        Require valid-user
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Authentication is bypassed and shows the site without a password request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your configuration is granting access from any address.

You need to remove the line `require all granted`.